# Setting Wallpaper Engine's Window Listener to Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on a wallpaper engine application in angular and the documentation says to grab a property off the window object and set it to a function to get the current user properties. I'm trying to convert this logic into angular but haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

[Here's what I'm trying to match](https://docs.wallpaperengine.io/en/web/api/propertylistener.html):

```
window.wallpaperPropertyListener = {
    applyUserProperties: function(properties) {
        if (properties.yourproperty) { // Don't forget to check if the property is included in the event
            // Checkbox / boolean example, change this as needed for your property type
            if (properties.yourproperty.value == true) {
                // Do something if your property is true
            } else {
                // Do something if your property is false
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Here's what I have:

app.module.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    wallpaperPropertyListener : any;
  }
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FuzzyTimeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'wordclock2';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    window.wallpaperPropertyListener = {
      applyUserProperties(properties) {
        this.settingsService.setTimePeriodEnabled(false);
      }
    };
  }
```

I'm not checking for any properties right now, since I just want to see if the function is ever called and it doesn't seem like it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using a d.ts file to declare an interface that matched the objects and functions I needed.

In a /src/types/global.d.ts file

```
export {}; // needed to make TypeScript happy

declare global {
  interface Window {
    wallpaperPropertyListener: {
        applyUserProperties: (properties: any) => void;
    }
  }
}
```

And then I was able to use it like this in my app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
window.wallpaperPropertyListener = {
  applyUserProperties: (properties) => {
    if (properties) {
      // Do what you want with the properties
    }
  },
};
```

}